# PHP multi dimensional array pushing is not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array and I want to push an another array to my multi dimensional array. I have used PHP array_push() function but it's not working. So how can I add another array to my multi dimensional array? Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
$array1 = ['id', 'name', 'age'];
$array2 = [
    [1, 'name1', 10],
    [2, 'name2', 20],
    [3, 'name3', 30]
];
```

Note: I want to have $array1 value on the top.

Comment: explain how your final array needs to be as well. for this example what should be your output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this issue PHP array_push(); function will not work. you have to use array_merge() to solve this and also need to create another array to keep those data.

I hope this code will solve your problem

```
$array1 = ['id', 'name', 'age'];
$array2 = [
    [1, 'name1', 10],
    [2, 'name2', 20],
    [3, 'name3', 30]
];

$array3 = array_merge([$array1], $array2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array3); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `$array3 = array_merge([$array1], $array2);` check your `print_r()`.

Comment: Whoops I missed to wrap $array1 in to another array. Thanks Abra Cadaver

Answer (score 5):

`array_push()` adds a new element to the end of the array. If you want a new element on the front instead, use `array_unshift()`:

```
$array1 = ['id', 'name', 'age'];
$array2 = [
    [1, 'name1', 10],
    [2, 'name2', 20],
    [3, 'name3', 30]
];
array_unshift($array2, $array1);
```

$array2 now looks like this:

```
[
    ['id', 'name', 'age'],
    [1, 'name1', 10],
    [2, 'name2', 20],
    [3, 'name3', 30]
];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `array_unshift` or more simple `$array2 = $array1 + $array2`